# Cycles of length $8$

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory

There is a construction of a bipartite graph $G=(V_1 \cup V_2, E),$ where $|V_1|=|V_2|=n,$ $|E| \geq \Omega(n^{6/5}),$ such that $G$ does not cotain any cycle of length $8.$

I was wondering if someone knows this construction or introduce me a reference for that?

Comment: Is there some additional hypothesis (presumably related to cycles of length 8)?  With no further hypothesis a bipartite graph on $n+n$ vertices can have as many as $n^2$ edges . . .

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies it got edited.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  These exist.  See the following, which more than answers the question.

https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9501231.pdf

Previous (some better/easier in your case) results also do this as well (regarding generalized hexagons).  The well-known conjecture is that $C_{2k}$-free graphs exist with $\approx n^{1+1/k}$ edges.  This would be best possible, but it’s still unknown for $C_8$-free graphs.

Answer (score 3):

The incidence graphs of [Generalized Hexagons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_polygon) provide a construction: Such a graph constructed fron the Lie group $G_2(q)$ ($q$ a prime power) has degree $(q+1)$ and $2(q^6-1)/(q-1)$ vertices, and is bipartite.

The problem better fits the [cage problem](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS16/pdf) framework: Such graphs correspond to girth $10$ or $12$. Cages of this girth would surely satisfy $|E|≥Ω(n^{6/5})$. Even if the cage is not known, there're methods to construct relatively small graphs for girth $12$ by removing a subgraph from a known cage. For girth $10$, there's no known general construction for $|E|≥Ω(n^{5/4})$.